# Adding an input field in a HTML form causes everything below it to take it's attributes

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

I have this HTML CSS combo to make a login form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hold your horses...</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<form class="box" action="/users/login" method="POST">
  <h1>Woah...</h1>
  <h2>You'll need to be logged in to do that</h2>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="" value="Login">
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #191919;
}
.box{
  width: 300px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: #191919;
  text-align: center;
}
.box h1{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.box h2{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: medium;
}
.box input[type = "text"],.box input[type = "password"]{
  border:0;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
.box input[type = "text"]:focus,.box input[type = "password"]:focus{
  width: 280px;
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.box input[type = "submit"], input[id = "submit"]{
  border:0;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
  padding: 14px 40px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box input[type = "submit"]:hover, input[id = "submit"]:hover{
  background: #2ecc71;
}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

However, when I add an addition field to my html form (it's hidden as it's a redirect link and doesn't need input from the user):

```
<form class="box" action="/users/login" method="POST">
  <h1>Woah...</h1>
  <h2>You'll need to be logged in to do that</h2>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="hidden" id="redirectURL" name="redirectURL" placeholder="" value=<%=redirectURL%> // <--- new line
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="" value="Login">
</form>
```

It causes everything below it (in this case the submit button) disappear taking it's 'hidden' attributes.

How would this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input` element is missing a closing tag. This can be fixed by using:

```
<input type="hidden" id="redirectURL" name="redirectURL" placeholder="" value=<%=redirectURL%>>
```

Comment: oh...now I feel stupid, thought it was something more complex that I was somehow missing? But no, I've wasted 2 hours stuck on this when it was just a simple > -_- Thanks!

Comment: Been there, mate - it happens to all of us :)

Comment: just need a fresh eye hahah, I'll mark it as the answer when it allows, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the hidden input element.

Add an extra `>` just after `value=<%=redirectURL%>`.